# Difficulty in understanding the proof of "The centre of every connected graph $G$ is a subgraph of some block of $G$"

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I was going through the text *A First Course in Graph Theory* by *Chartrand, Zhang*. There I came across the above theorem and it's proof. But I had difficulty in understanding it in few places.

> Theorem : *The center of every connected graph $G$ is a subgraph of some block of $G$.*
>
> Proof:
>
> 1. Assume, to the contrary, that $G$ is a connected graph whose center $Cen(G)$ is not a subgraph of a single block of $G$.
> 2. Then there is a cut-vertex $v$ of $G$ such that **$G-v$ contains two components $G_1$ and $G_2$**, each of which contains vertices of $Cen(G)$.
> 3. Let $u$ be a vertex of $G$ such that $d(u,v)=e(v)$ and let $P_1$ be a $u-v$ geodesic in $G$.
> 4. **At least one of $G_1$ and $G_2$ contains no vertices of $P_1$**. Say $G_2$ contains no vertices of $P_1$.
> 5. Let $w$ be a central vertex of $G$ that belongs to $G_2$ and let $P_2$ be a $v-w$ geodesic.
> 6. Then $P_1$ followed by $P_2$ produces a $u-w$  geodesic, whose length is greater than that of $P_1$.
> 7. Hence $e(w)>e(v)$, which contradicts the fact that $w$ is a central vertex of $G$.

---

Now in point $(3)$ the authors assume that $G-v$ has two components (exactly)? then again in point $(4)$ "At least one of $G_1$ and $G_2$ contains no vertices of $P_1$". If none of the components contain vertices of $P_1$ then where will the vertices go? I guess the authors meant **$G-v$ contains *at least* two components of which $G_1$ and $G_2$ contains vertices of $Cen(G)$** in point $(3)$.

---

In the proof where are we using the fact, that vertices of $Cen(G)$ belongs to two separate blocks? While proving we assume $w \in V[Cen(G)]$ to belong to $G_2$, where I feel we are only considering a single vertex in a single component. Now suppose if $w$ is the single vertex present in $V[Cen(G)]$, then as per this proof we still arrive at a contradiction I guess. This is the part which I cannot understand...

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I guess the authors meant $G−v$ contains at least two components of which $G_1$ and $G_2$ contains vertices of $Cen(G)$ in point (3).

Yes, that's what the authors mean.

> In the proof where are we using the fact, that vertices of Cen(G) belongs to two separate blocks?

This is used in point (4). Specifically, the vertices of $P_1 - v$ are contained in a single connected component of $G-v$. This component can be $G_1$, $G_2$, or some other connected component of $G-v$. Since both $G_1$ and $G_2$ contains a central vertex, in all three cases we can find a central vertex not contained in the same component, which is what we need for the rest of the proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help...